# Does Delphi have isqrt?

Tags: delphi, math

I'm doing some heavy work on large integer numbers in UInt64 values, and was wondering if Delphi has an [integer square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) function.
Fow now I'm using `Trunc(Sqrt(x*1.0))` but I guess there must be a more performant way, perhaps with a snippet of inline assembler? (`Sqrt(x)`with `x:UInt64` throws an invalid type compiler error in D7, hence the `*1.0` bit.)

Comment: Yeah, the `*1.0` was fixed in a later version.  Not sure which later version, but it definitely works correctly in D2010.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am very far from an expert on assembly, so this answer is just me fooling around.

However, this seems to work:

```
function isqrt(const X: Extended): integer;
asm
  fld X
  fsqrt
  fistp @Result
  fwait
end;
```

as long as you set the FPU control word's rounding setting to "truncate" prior to calling `isqrt`. The easiest way might be to define the helper function

```
function SetupRoundModeForSqrti: word;
begin
  result := Get8087CW;
  Set8087CW(result or $600);
end;
```

and then you can do

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  oldCW: word;
begin
  oldCW := SetupRoundModeForSqrti; // setup CW
  // Compute a few million integer square roots using isqrt here
  Set8087CW(oldCW); // restore CW
end;
```

## Test

Does this really improve performance? Well, I tested

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  oldCW: word;
  p1, p2: Int64;
  i: Integer;
  s1, s2: string;
const
  N = 10000000;
begin
  oldCW := SetupRoundModeForSqrti;

  QueryPerformanceCounter(p1);
  for i := 0 to N do
    Tag := isqrt(i);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(p2);
  s1 := inttostr(p2-p1);

  QueryPerformanceCounter(p1);
  for i := 0 to N do
    Tag := trunc(Sqrt(i));
  QueryPerformanceCounter(p2);
  s2 := inttostr(p2-p1);

  Set8087CW(oldCW);

  ShowMessage(s1 + #13#10 + s2);
end;
```

and got the result

```
371802
371774.
```

Hence, it is simply not worth it. The naive approach `trunc(sqrt(x))` is far easier to read and maintain, has superior future and backward compatibility, and is less prone to errors.

Comment: Ah, explanation is no longer necessary. Happy compensating then.

Comment: @Worm: We don't really care about the downvote, it's just much more valuable if you explain the reason behind it so that everyone can learn. That's what SO is all about, after all.

Comment: Hmm, could you fool me around a version that has parameter and result of type UInt64?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer is no it does not have an integer square root function and that your solution is reasonable.

I'm a bit surprised at the need to multiple by 1.0 to convert to a floating point value. I think that must be a Delphi bug and more recent versions certainly behave as you would wish.

Comment: There's more, I'm past the 2^32 mark now, and I get EInvalidOp: Invalid floating point operation on my trick... I guess I'm down to implementing the old-skool algorhythm of calculating the isqrt step by step...

Comment: @stijn are you returning into a uint64?

Comment: Trunc does according to the help... It's the `Sqrt(x*1.0)` that's failing

Comment: @Stijn It's all perfectly fine in the latest versions of Delphi. And it works fine for me in Delphi 6. Could you post a very cut-down version of your code as an update to your question. Just a single routine that fails. I'm sure it won't take much sorting out.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I end up using, based on [one of the algorhythms listed on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29)

```
type
  baseint=UInt64;//or cardinal for the 32-bit version
function isqrt(x:baseint):baseint;
var
  p,q:baseint;
begin
  //get highest power of four
  p:=0;
  q:=4;
  while (q<>0) and (q<=x) do
   begin
    p:=q;
    q:=q shl 2;
   end;
  //
  q:=0;
  while p<>0 do
   begin
    if x>=p+q then
     begin
      dec(x,p);
      dec(x,q);
      q:=(q shr 1)+p;
     end
    else
      q:=q shr 1;
    p:=p shr 2;
   end;
  Result:=q;
end;
```